# jQuery functions not working after Infinite Scroll (AJAX) with Masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

this may get complicated so I will try to explain my situation as best as I can.

I am using this jquery plugin http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ along with masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Everything is working fine.

However, I'm trying to make some info relating to each post appear when you hover over a post. Here is my code:

```
$(".main").hover(function(){
    $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

This only works on the first page content and not the extra content that is loaded by the infinite scroll.

So I tried adding the function to the callback of my masonry code:

```
    // trigger Masonry as a callback
function(newElements) {
    // hide new items while they are loading
    var $newElems = $(newElements).css({opacity: 0});
    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout
    $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
        // show elems now they're ready
        $newElems.animate({opacity: 1});
        $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true); 
    });
    $(".main").hover(function(){
        $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast");
    });     
});
```

(Excuse me if I'm doing this completely wrong, I have never worked with Ajax before and am merely experimenting)

This made the hover function work on the new extra content loaded by Infinite scroll, however it then conflicted with the original content.

So, what is the best way to implement my hover function so it will work properly for all posts loaded before and after the Ajax call?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

Solved the problem by changing my method to this:

```
    $(document).on("click",".main",function(){
    $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/on/

I will leave the original question here incase someone with a similar problem finds it useful.

Comment: To mark the question as solved, you should answer your question, then mark it as accepted. Do not put the answer as edit into question.

Comment: @Imp I tried that but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I think you just have to wait a bit...

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click",".main",function(){
    $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For latest version of http://www.infinite-scroll.com/ along with masonry: http://masonry.desandro.com/ following code worked for me:

```
 $grid.on( 'append.infiniteScroll', function( event, response, path, items ) {
        $(this).next(".info").slideToggle("fast"); 
      // OR your code you want to load after infinite scroll loads
    });
```

Check for more here https://infinite-scroll.com/events.html#append